# REPEATABLE READ isolation level at update method is meaningful?

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

The Repeatable Read isolation level only sees data committed before the transaction began.
So, I think it is only meaningful at Method doing repeat select.
But, I see a below code.

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ)
@Override
public void buyItem(Credit playerCredit, Long haveToPayCredit) {
    if(haveToPayCredit > playerCredit.getFreeCredit()) {
        Long remainHaveToPay = haveToPayCredit - playerCredit.getFreeCredit();
        playerCredit.updateCredit(playerCredit.getPaidCredit() - remainHaveToPay, 0L);
    }
    else {
        playerCredit.updateCredit(playerCredit.getPaidCredit(), playerCredit.getFreeCredit() - haveToPayCredit);
    }
}
```

This method do only update. So, It look so meaningless to add Transactional annotation.
The REPEATABLE READ isolation level at update method is meaningful?

Comment: Most likely this expression actually does reading `haveToPayCredit > playerCredit.getFreeCredit()`. So it is doubtfully only updating. In this case I would say that repeatable read is even dangerous. See my question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/76415638/520567