# REPEATABLE READ transaction isolation level dangerous for most apps

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, isolation-level

this question is broader than Rails but this is where most of my observations come from so using it as a basis.

I discovered some transient issues in an app I'm working on, where REPEATABLE READ ([the default for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html)) transaction isolation level made much more probable than with READ COMMITTED which is the default for PostgreSQL, oracle and I believe others.

The thing boils down to simplified read and update code like:

```rb
if order.pending?
  order.process
end
```

There is similar code in probably every app. And if this code is run within a transaction, then isolation level can increase or decrease the chances that concurrent workers trying to work on the same `order` will `process` it more than once.

I understand that there is another issue with the app in the first place that an order could be attempted to be processed twice, but still bugs pop-up everywhere so decreasing chances of incorrect processing is important either way.

If REPEATABLE READ isolation level is used, and 2 workers started transactions relatively at the same time to process a single order, then second transaction will not see that the order was processed even after first transaction committed the changes.

When READ COMMITTED is used, then at least after first transaction committed, the second one will see them, thus reducing the time window where a concurrent transaction will perform duplicated processing.

More thorough explanation of this phenomenon can be found [in medium article](https://vipulbest1.medium.com/handling-concurrency-through-database-in-rails-part-2-136e5420bce0).

So my observation is that despite REPEATABLE READ providing a "higher" level of guarantees, for the common application it has more harmful effects + reduced performance of the database engine compared to the "lower" level guarantees of READ COMMITTED.

And the question is whether I miss **common** app usage scenarios where REPEATABLE READ would be safer? Can we **commonly** see application types where a default of REPEATABLE READ will make more sense than READ COMMITTED?

I mean something that is common, not isolated specific parts of the app that are better served by enforcing isolation level for that part of the app only.

Comment: "probable" ?...

Comment: @RickJames, `probable, adjective, Likely to happen or to be true`. Idk if "more" can be used together with "probably", not a native speaker. But with that definition from dictionary it makes some sense "more Likely to happen".

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL's default, this works well with the default isolation:

Case 1:  A "fast" process:

```
START TRANSACTION;
$task = SELECT ... FOR UPDATE;
perform $task
UPDATE/DELETE -- remove item from queue.
COMMIT;
```

Case 2:  If the task processing takes "too long", do not depend on database transaction to "lock" the task:

```
START TRANSACTION;  (only long enough to find and lock queue entry)
$id = SELECT ... FOR UPDATE; (find something to process)
UPDATE queue  SET
        who_owns = $me,
        checkout_time = NOW()
    WHERE id = $id;
COMMIT;

Process the task (with transaction(s) if needed)

(If this is a single statement,
    then simply depend on `autocommit=ON` to handle ACID.)
DELETE queue
    WHERE id = $id
```

You should have a "reaper" to take care of queue items that get checked out by some worker but where the worker dies prematurely.

That is the secret is `READ COMMITTED`, `FOR UPDATE`, *and* don't try to hang onto the row "too long".

When two threads reach for the same task, one will get it, the other will either pause for "lock_wait_timeout" or get a deadlock.  For a deadlock, simply retry.

Comment: Honestly I have zero idea how this addresses the question. How is in these examples the REPEATABLE READ better than READ COMMITTED? btw, as I wrote, that order is a simple example. In an old bloated app, you never know everything that is going to be checked and touched to lock on all of these, would be error prone anyway.